# if I want to send text What should I find_element_by_?

Tags: python, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver, findelement

```
<input _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c28="" type="text" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber-input" autocomplete="cc-number" required="" maxlength="23" ccnumber="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">
```

if I want to send text in label What should i find_element_by_?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56yGi.png)

Comment: What label? You're showing us an input element with an ID='cardNumber-input'. If you want to interact with said input element then I'd recommend `find_element_by_id`.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel it's error : raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="cardNumber-input"]"}

Comment: Then you're not getting the HTML you expected. Perhaps the content is loaded via javascript. Post how you are getting the HTML and, if you can, the URL.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel What do i need to do

Comment: Post how you are getting the HTML and, if you can, the URL.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I use driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverpath) driver.get(url)

Comment: Without more of your code and the URL then I do not see how we can help you. Perhaps the element is in an iframe, perhaps it has not had time to load yet. We cannot tell, can we?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel html : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XhA4A8JRdNYwmO1-qZr9iB3iF456Cez9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That HTML does not even contain the ID in your question. What URL are you passing to `driver.get(...)`?